# Python pip package installation

Tags: python, pip, package

What's the difference between 
`pip install pkg_name` and
`pip install -U pkg_name`?

Does it automatically install the dependencies too or something?

Comment: `-U` means upgrade respective package to latest version

Answer (score 0):

If we do `pip install -h` we see:

```
 -U, --upgrade               Upgrade all specified packages to the newest
                              available version.
```

So it upgrades the packages you specify (they can be already installed)